# proof of the admissibility of Harrop's rule

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Can we prove formally using sequents in LJ that Harrop's rule $(\neg A \rightarrow B \lor C) \rightarrow (\neg A \rightarrow B) \lor (\neg A \rightarrow C)$ is admissible, i.e. $\vdash_{LJ} \neg A \rightarrow B \lor C $ $\implies$ $\vdash_{LJ} (\neg A \rightarrow B) \lor (\neg A \rightarrow C)$ ?
I am wondering how we could rigorously prove the admissibility of Harrop's rule. I am interested in that because it is the standard example to show that a rule may be admissible but not derivable. I am just trying to know how we can prove such "meta-theoric" results.

Comment: Please edit your Question to add some *context*.  Although you've stated a problem that can be solved by reasoned mathematical argument, it will improve the content for Readers if the source of the problem, what you tried, or what makes it interesting/challenging is shared.

Comment: What do you mean by "prove formally using sequents"? The statement "Harrop's rule is admissible" is a statement of the meta theory, not a statement of the object theory LJ, so it doesn't make sense to talk about proving it in LJ. Perhaps what you want is some kind of very explicit proof that proceeds by induction on the structure an arbitrary given proof of $\lnot A \to B\lor C$ in LJ, and transforms it into a proof of $(\lnot A\to B) \lor (\lnot A\to C)$?

Comment: Does the proof of Theorem 2 in these notes answer your question? https://homepage.mi-ras.ru/~sk/lehre/penn2017/lecture_Gentzen.pdf

Comment: Those interested may wish to take a glance at [a previous question on Harrop's rule](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256795/admissibility-of-harrops-rule-computationally) beforehand.

Comment: Yes, sorry maybe I am not very clear on the subject. I was wondering how we could rigorously prove the admissibility of Harrop's rule. I am interested in that because it is the standard example to show that a rule may be admissible but not derivable. I am just trying to know how we can prove such "meta-theoric" results.  Thanks for the answers, the links are very instructive

Comment: The last Comment you left has the kind of context that would improve your Question.  Please edit the body of your Question to include it, as it gives Readers better information about the kind of response that will be useful to you.